# Load files with FreeImage to PySide

Tags: python, load, pyside, freeimage

I am trying to use smc.FreeImage to load a .NEF files (Nikon Camera RAW) and Display with PySide.

I found this example that loads and displays the commented .JPG file just fine, but it crashes when I replace the pixmap with a FI.Image NEF.

I added the print pixmap.getInfoHeader to make sure the .NEF actually loads which it does, I see the correct Header information in the output window.

How do I translate the read pixmap = FI.Image so that PySide understands it ? I've seen people using numpy and PIL tostring but none of those examples seems to cover this case.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from smc import freeimage as FI

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

        #pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("Somefile.jpg")
        pixmap = FI.Image("Anotherfile.NEF")
        print( pixmap.getInfoHeader() )

        lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

        hbox.addWidget(lbl)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('Da window Title')
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what is error message? What is your Python experience level? Are you aware that FI.Image is different object type and might have different methods?

Comment: Well I am rather new to Python but I am aware that they are different objects, that is why I am asking how to "translate" it so pySide understand it. I've seen it been done with PIL loading the image and figured there would be a similar way with smc.FreeImage.
And the error message is as follows.


`TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QLabel.setPixmap' called with wrong argument types:

  PySide.QtGui.QLabel.setPixmap(smc.freeimage._freeimage.Image)
Supported signatures:

  PySide.QtGui.QLabel.setPixmap(PySide.QtGui.QPixmap)
`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your minimal example.
Instead of using the smc module you can simple create a new QPixmap object and giving the path to the *.nef file as constructor parameter.

```
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("Path_To_File.NEF")
lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

I have tested your example and it worked without any problems.